# Difference between "в тишине" and "в тишину"?

Tags: падежи, предлоги, существительные, винительный-падеж

What is the difference between `в тишине` and `в тишину`? I know the first one is the prepositional singular of `тишина`, and the second is the accusative singular of `тишина`, but I don't really understand the different use cases.

This question arose from the lyrics from a song, specifically: `Она на полупальцах в тишину.` Here I would have thought it should be `в тишине`? Or is it because she is moving *towards* silence, as opposed to in it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your guess is correct. "В тишине" is being in a silence, while "в тишину" is a poetic expression (and you will hardly encounter it in a colloquial conversation, as well as «на полупальцах» by the way)- she went away into the silence. For instance, "он сидел в темноте и думал" - he was sitting in a dark place, while "он ушёл в темноту"  - he went away into the darkness.

Answer (score 1):

- В чём? - В тишине.
- Куда? - В тишину.

Regardless of whether the expression is used in a poetic sense or not, asking the above questions will help you define the correct spelling or reading of the written words

Comment: Hi and welcome to Russian.SE! We prefer longer, more thorough questions and answers here on this site. Two-liners like this are not really helpful, especially for a person who seems to be aware about the Russian cases. Could you please expand your answer a little bit? Thanks!